# Prevent keyUp event when onPaste event is triggered

Tags: javascript

I have the following input field:

```
<input onPaste={pasteFunction} keyUp={keyupFunction} />
```

I want either the `pasteFunction` or `keyupFunction` to run, NOT both. But when a user pastes text into this field both events get triggered and both run.

Is there a way to prevent keyUp if something was pasted into the field?

I tried to set a flag and reset it:

```
function pasteFunction() {
  pasteInProgress = true;
  //etc...
  pasteInProgress = false;
}

function keyupFunction() {
  if (pasteInProgress) return;
  //etc...
}
```

But this doesn't work as pasteInProgress is set to false before keyupFunction is triggered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try storing the time instead, for example.

```
function pasteFunction() {
  lastPaste = Date.now();
  //etc...

}

function keyupFunction() {
  //less than one second has passed.
  if (Date.now()-lastPaste<1000) return;
  //etc...
}
```

Maybe try experimenting with different times depending on the application, but it is still a "hacky" way to solve it. I think there could be better ways.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to prevent keyUp if something was pasted into the field?

Assuming you are using a ui library (react?), you could store a value in the component state when something was pasted into the field.

```
this.state = {
  hasPasted: false;
}

function pasteFunction() {
  this.state.hasPasted = true; // could also be a timestamp if you need granularity
}

function keyupFunction(e) { // assuming you can pass event here
  if (this.state.hasPasted){
    // you may want to preventDefault() here
    e.preventDefault();
    return;
  };
}
```

Without you sharing more context/code, this should do it.